# Checkpoint code in text editor (like a micro version control)

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, version-control

When I'm editing code, I want to periodically checkpoint my code (ranging from every 10-20 minutes to a few hours). Consider it as a micro version control at local level & something that I discard  at the end of the day. Basically after certain edits, I save the file with a flag (a checkpoint or milestone) & move on. Then maybe later, revert back to it for a shortwhile.

I do not want to commit this to the main version control & I want this to be extremely seamless (like press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Is this possible in a text editor or with a plugin. Currently I'm using Sublime Text 2. There's an autosave plugin that keeps saving a timestamped file whenever I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> but the shortcoming is that I can't annotate my saved file with  a flag. I suppose it's possible to modify the plugin to have this functionality. Wondering if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to request such a plugin at ST3 community, so it can make BAKs with a description.

Other option is make symlink for a folder, and push symlink's folder to Git with BAT file.